# Login with 2 different table in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.4.3. I've try several methods from many tutorials but still can't make this login works. There are 2 different tables for my login page. `mst_pelajar` for `ROLE_USER` with `nis` field as username and `mst_pegawai` for `ROLE_ADMIN` with `na` field as username.

I can make it works for `in_memory` username and password definitions. I try to make this login system works by insert plain text into database first. I get `bad credentials` error with this settings.

Here my security.yml :

```
security:
    encoders:
        #Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity\MstPelajar: plaintext
        Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity\MstPegawai: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        #ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        #ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
    #in_memory:
    #    memory:
    #        users:
    #            user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
    #            admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

        admin_area:
            entity: { class: SifoAdminBundle:MstPegawai, property: na }
        user_area:
            entity: { class: SifoAdminBundle:MstPelajar, property: nis }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
            anonymous: true
        alogin:
            pattern:  ^/admin/login$
            security: false
            anonymous: true
        ulogin:
            pattern:  ^/user/login$
            security: false
            anonymous: true
        admin_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            anonymous: false
            form_login:
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                login_path: /admin/login
            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /admin
        user_area:
            pattern: ^/user
            anonymous: false
            form_login: 
                check_path: /user/login_check
                login_path: /user/login
            logout:
                path:   /user/logout
                target: /user

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/user/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Entity for admin :

```
<?php

namespace Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * MstPelajar
 */
class MstPelajar implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

     * @var string
     */
    private $nis;


    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $aktif;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $timestamp;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $operator;

    private $username;

    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param integer $id
     * @return MstPelajar
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Set nis
     *
     * @param string $nis
     * @return MstPelajar
     */
    public function setNis($nis)
    {
        $this->nis = $nis;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nis
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNis()
    {
        return $this->nis;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return MstPelajar
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return MstPelajar
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->aktif = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->nis;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->nis,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->nis,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

The user entity almost same with admin, I'll make admin login work first after get the problem. I just show important field at top.

Here my DefaultController for admin :

```
<?php

namespace Sifo\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

use Sifo\AdminBundle\Form\DefaultType;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('SifoAdminBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }

public function loginAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return $this->render('SifoAdminBundle:Default:login.html.twig', array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just fix my problem. I need to add provider in my firewall. It will be look like this :

```
security:
    encoders:
        #Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity\MstPelajar: plaintext
        Sifo\AdminBundle\Entity\MstPegawai: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        #ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        #ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        #in_memory:
        #    memory:
        #        users:
        #            user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
        #            admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
        admin_area:
            entity: { class: SifoAdminBundle:MstPegawai, property: na }
        user_area:
            entity: { class: SifoAdminBundle:MstPelajar, property: nis }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
            anonymous: true
        alogin:
            pattern: ^/admin/login$
            security: false
            anonymous: true
        ulogin:
            pattern: ^/user/login$
            security: false
            anonymous: true
        admin_area:
            pattern: ^/admin
            provider: admin_area
            anonymous: false
            form_login:
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                login_path: /admin/login
            logout:
                path: /admin/logout
                target: /admin
        user_area:
            pattern: ^/user
            provider: user_area
            anonymous: false
            form_login: 
                check_path: /user/login_check
                login_path: /user/login
            logout:
                path: /user/logout
                target: /user

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/user/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```