# Symfony 2 login form cannot login

Tags: php, symfony, login-control

I am creating a login form that connects to the user table. But, when I submit the login form it generates this message "*The user provider must return a UserInterface object.*"

I have created the user entity from the user.orm.yml Am I missing something???

**Security.yml**

security:

```
encoders:
    ESS\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
        algorithm: plaintext
        encode-as-base64: true
        iterations: 1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: ESSUserBundle:User}
```

**UserRepository Class**

```
namespace ESS\UserBundle\Repository;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $q = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery();

        try {
            // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
            // if there is no record matching the criteria.
            $user = $q->getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException $e) {
            $message = sprintf(
                'Unable to find an active admin AcmeUserBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
                $username
            );
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message, 0, $e);
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $class = get_class($user);
        if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf(
                    'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
                    $class
                )
            );
        }

        return $this->find($user->getId());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $this->getEntityName() === $class
            || is_subclass_of($class, $this->getEntityName());
    }
}
```

**User Entity Class**

```
namespace ESS\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 * 
 * 
 */
class User
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;
```

Comment: Does your user class implement the [UserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html) from the Symfony framework?

Comment: I am authenticating with custom entity provider and I have added my entity class above

Comment: I think you missing providers in your firewall security. Please check my question and answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517034/login-with-2-different-table-in-symfony2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your user entity itself needs to implement Symfony2's user interface. 
http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html

Add this to the top of your entity file.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface; 



class User implements UserInterface {
```

And then implement the methods in the interface.

Symfony's security component require users to implement this interface to be able to authenticate them.

Comment: When I implement UserInterface to User class I get following message

\ESS\UserBundle\Entity\User is not abstract and does not override abstract method  getRoles() in \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface

Comment: in your Entity @Sudin, check my link in your question comments.

Comment: @Sudin, you need to create actually implementations of the methods defined in the UserInterface and return the correct data types.

Comment: [Solved] I just added three methods getRoles(), getSalt() and eraseCredentials() to the User entity and it worked perfectly. Thank you all for your support.

Comment: If I do not use username field then why its required to implement getUsername() method ? Is there any way to not implement getUsername method if I don't use it in the form.

Comment: @Aamir The reason username is required is actually unrelated to the form. When a user is loaded (logged in) by Symfony, its done through a UseProvider (an implementation of http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserProviderInterface.html). As you can see, the loadUserByUsername in this interface requires a single argument, the username. You can use whatever you want as the username though, as long as it uniquely identifies the user (so you could just have the username return the user's email if you so choose).